# How to count same keys data from array in PHP

Tags: php

I have array like below I want to convert it as per requirement

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2017-01-23] => 5885e363e4b0e341d3e47fc3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2017-01-23] => 5885e4f9e4b0e341d3e47fd7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2017-01-24] => 5885e363e4b0e341d3e47fc3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2017-01-24] => 5885e4f9e4b0e341d3e47fd7
        )

  )
```

I want count of same key data as in output. That is I want to count of same keys so that i want to plot it on graph

```
 Array
(
   [0]=>Array
   (
     [2017-01-23]=> 2
   )
   [1]=>Array
   (
     [2017-01-24]=> 2
   )
)
```

Comment: anything you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $temp = array();

 $array = array(
  '0' => Array
  (
    '333' => 2,
    '222' => 5,
    '444' => 4
  ),
  '1' => Array
    (
    '111' => 2
  ),
  '2' => Array
    (
    '111' => 5,
    '222' => 9
  )
 );

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
      if (!isset($temp[$k]))
      {
        $temp[$k] = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        $temp[$k] = $temp[$k]+1;
      }
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($temp);
die;
```

Output :

```
Array
(
  [333] => 1
  [222] => 2
  [444] => 1
  [111] => 2
)
```

Comment: Anytime  brother  :)